# What are the different ways an accent mark can go over the letter A & how are they pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, accent, diacritics

I've found specifically these ones: á, à, â, å, ä.  I believe they COULD be used in the English language, or root ones such as Celtic & Germanic, but I don't know how they are pronounced.

Oh, and I've glanced at the articles [What does the grave accent mark on words mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35347/what-does-the-grave-accent-mark-on-words-mean) and [Diacritic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) if that helps jumpstart you on your assistance.  Thank you, and *please* give examples of how they are used!

Comment: They're really not used in modern English

Comment: By the way, Celtic is not a root language of English, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @MarkBeadles, in fact, *Celtic* is not a language at all. :)

Comment: No more or less than Germanic is :)

Answer (score 6):

The uses of diacritic marks in modern English are quite limited, and diacritic marks can **always** be omitted without being incorrect. This applies equally to **A** and any other letter.

**Recent foreign borrowings**: e.g. [rôle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15488/what-is-the-distinction-between-role-and-role-with-a-circumflex), [coup d'état](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coup_d%27%C3%A9tat), [façade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%87#In_loanwords_only), etc. but role, coup d'etat, and facade are also all correct.

**Stage and poetry prosody**:  e.g. [learnèd](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35347/what-does-the-grave-accent-mark-on-words-mean) indicating a normally silent vowel is to be pronounced

**Diaeresis**: e.g. [Brontë](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bront%C3%AB_family#Origin_of_the_name), Chloë, Zoë (also indicating a silent vowel is to be pronounced) or naïve, Boötes, and [noël](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noel) (indicating a vowel is to be pronounced separately).

**Artistic or humorous effect**: e.g. Blue Öyster Cult

As for pronunciation: in English, including or not including the diacritic does not change the pronunciation, though it may clarify it. In other languages diacritics have many different pronunciations and you would have to look at each language for details.

Comment: Sorry, I really can’t agree with you that **facade* should be considered correct. There is no other word in the English language that has a soft *c* preceding an *a*.  It is insane to create a brand new never-before-seen rule for just one single word.  Either mark it correctly, or respell it to conform to the rule of English.

Comment: Given how seldom English is spelled with any diacritics, facade is probably inevitable. It's certainly in dictionaries.

Comment: @tchrist: much as it may pain a purist, _facade_ is evidently considered correct enough by publishers like [Wiley](http://www.amazon.com/Historic-Building-Facades-Rehabilitation-Preservation/dp/0471144150/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8), [Infinity](http://www.amazon.com/Facades-Mildred-Dumas/dp/0741438887/ref=sr_1_32?s=books&ie=UTF8), and the [UCal Press](http://www.amazon.com/Behind-Postmodern-Facade-Architectural-Twentieth-Century/dp/0520201612/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8).

Comment: OED lists façade not facade, but includes both spellings among its citations, e.g. "*1656   T. Blount Glossographia,   Facade [sic], the fore-front forepart, outside or representation of the outside of a house.*", "*1796   J. Morse Amer. Universal Geogr. (new ed.) I. 754   Their estates [in Demerara] are regularly laid out in lots along the sea shore, called facades [sic]*"; sics mine.

Comment: @tchrist [The New York Times uses the **c** *sans cedille*](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/08/28/nyregion/building-with-weathering-steel-both-rugged-and-rusty.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0) so I'm really going to have to call *facade* 'correct' if there is any such thing.

Comment: @MarkBeadles You believe haphazardly adding brand new one-shot rules for individual words in a system already burgeoning with complexity is a good thing?  I call it foul, and hold my position: mark it correctly, or respell it to fit within the existing parameters of English spelling instead of fabricating a new one.  Either is acceptable.  Doing neither is ridiculous and cumbersome.

Comment: @tchrist I'm sceptical of your indictment, but am too tired to respond as my muscles are still flaccid after my recent soccer game.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from rare accented E, there's no diacritics in English. In any case, all modified letters are pronounced as per particular foreign word in question, as specific words are often pronounced specifically, apart from the generic sound implied by a diacritic.

Comment: You mean pronunciation of foreign languages is respected when words are taken into English? Not on my planet.

Comment: To the extent that they manage, as in usually diluted down to bare minimum.