# Is someone "casted" or "cast" in a film role?

Tags: confusables, irregular-verbs

Can the word 'casted' be used in this headline?

[image]

> Michael Fassbender Casted In Upcoming "Kung Fury" movie

Comment: See discussion at: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94565/can-casted-be-the-past-tense-of-cast

Comment: @KarlG I'da thot so too, but that *cast* is different. This *cast* probably works better with an "-ed" past tense, sounds better to me.

Comment: "In current usage, however, *casted* is gaining ground, especially where cast means either (1) *to assemble actors for a performance*, or (2) *to throw out bait and/or a lure on a fishing line*. (Both these senses have extended metaphorical uses where *casted* is likewise used at least some of the time). Many people object to *casted*, but that doesn’t change the fact that it is catching on and not likely to go away soon. "Jessica Biel, left, and Jaime Foxx, centre front, star in Garry Marshall’s impressively casted romantic comedy Valentine’s Day." http://grammarist.com/usage/casted/

Comment: Obviously answered at [Can “casted” be the past tense of “cast”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94565/can-casted-be-the-past-tense-of-cast).

Comment: That grammarist quote is part of the discussion of the linked question. The NOW corpus shows over 1000 hits for _casted_, most in the theatrical sense, but also _casted a vote_, esp. from outside UK and US. COCA has theatrical sense, but lots of spoken _casted vote_.

Comment: I conclude that the writer of that headline is not a native speaker of English.  However, I understand him, so why would I object?

Answer (score 0):

According to Merriam Webster's dictionary, cast can have the following definition: "to assign (someone, such as an actor) to a role or part." In this case, the past tense of cast is being used to say that he has already been assigned the roll in the past. Therefore, this word casted is okay to use in this scenario. An easier way to think about this is to place a synonym for casted in the headline to see if it works the same way. A word like assigned fits and has a similar meaning in this case.

Comment: Hello, Jonathan. Not a wrong answer, but answering questions where OP could have easily found the answer themself by a little basic research is not considered the best way to operate on ELU. It encourages further off-topic questions.

Comment: I would have thought the past tense of 'cast' was 'cast'.

Comment: It should be cast, and also 'rôle' not roll! Unless he's making serious dough in the movies.... 

Comment: Actually, returning here, M-W does not license 'casted' as a past participle (though I'd say this is a fault). But if this were not a duplicate, another reference would be necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Edwin. I apologize for answering this question, but I believed I knew the answer to it and could provide the OP with the answer in a short paragraph. Also, rôle and role are used interchangeably in modern usage (see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15488/what-is-the-distinction-between-role-and-r%C3%B4le-with-a-circumflex)